# How to write text on a huge bitmap

Tags: android, memory, canvas, bitmap, out-of-memory

I'm writing a simple camera app, that would let the user take a picture, and the app would write some information into the image.

I'm getting out of memory errors, because the image could be huge. Depends on the camera hardware.

This is how I'm writing the text onto the image:

```
public static byte[] writeTextOnImage(byte[] imgData, String text) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgData, 0, imgData.length);
    Bitmap mutableBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, true);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    int dist = 30;
    Rect areaRect = new Rect(dist, mutableBitmap.getHeight() - dist, 170, (int) (mutableBitmap.getHeight() - dist * 1.6f));

    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawRect(areaRect, paint);

    RectF bounds = new RectF(areaRect);
    bounds.right = paint.measureText(text, 0, text.length());
    bounds.bottom = paint.descent() - paint.ascent();

    bounds.left += (areaRect.width() - bounds.right) / 2.0f;
    bounds.top += (areaRect.height() - bounds.bottom) / 2.0f;

    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawText(text, bounds.left, bounds.top - paint.ascent(), paint);

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    mutableBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}
```

I guess I should not even think about loading the whole image, but I still have to write on it somehow. Is it possible to edit an image file without loading all of it into the memory?

Comment: do you have to write the Text on the image or is other solutions works too?

Comment: i think you want to have kind of label or watermark... is it?

Comment: yes. it has to be on the image. exif data is also there.

Comment: so Bitmap with TextView on it and just screenshot the screen wont work?

Comment: nope, I need the full resolution image

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate image in NDK. Memory available to native code is limited only by device RAM. Downside is that you have to decode image in native code.

Comment: that sound like a huge effort. I don't know C.